# Print an element that has visibility hidden set on the parent div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following HTML with an inline style of `visibility:hidden`.I would like to print the element when `ctrl+p` . It works with `display:none` but I do not want to use it as I would like the element to take up space on the page.

Following is my implementation

```
<div
    className="d-print-block mt-2"
    style={{
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        marginBottom: '1rem',
        visibility: 'hidden' // changing it to display:none works fine
    }}
>
    <div className="col-12">
        <div>This is hidden but needs to be printed</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you may have a css rule that sets the visibility css property of that element inside a media query for print https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#targeting_media_types. Something like `@media print { #idselector{visibility: visible;} }
` Anyway I'm confused hearing that if it had set `display: none` it was visible in the print

Comment: I think you can use jQuery to detect the ctrl+p event and then change the visibility style of the element to 'visible'.

Comment: @DiegoD : setting it to display:none shows up because of the class `d-print-block`.

Comment: with jQuery

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 80) { // detect ctrl+p
        $('.d-print-block').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
});

Comment: @Gihan it's a waste using javascript to set the style of elements when you are going to print. It will also change the view on screen and there's a much better way using css alone as suggested already

Answer (score 3):

Use `@media print` to override `visibility: hidden`:

HTML

```html
<div
    class="d-print-block mt-2 hide-for-print"
>
    <div class="col-12">
        <div>This is hidden but needs to be printed</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
  .hide-for-print {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  @media print {
    .hide-for-print {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/tomashubelbauer/pen/gOjzoNj)